# Fabric fails to install

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to add `Fabric` to my project, which is using `CocoaPods` with `Carthage`.  What I did:

1. In `Fabric` app, I've created a new app
2. In the project I've created new run script called 'Fabric', copied the code from `Fabric` app (the script is the last script in my project!)
3. Because the framework file couldn't be found, I've added proper path to `Framework Search Paths`.
4. I've also added `Fabric` framework to my project `Link Binary with Libraries` stage.

The project still does not build. The error:

```
2015-07-14 10:51:30.161 run[46263:967908] Fabric.framework/run 1.3.16
2015-07-14 10:51:30.169 run[46263:967908] 

Fabric: dSYM Error

Unable to process MyApp.app.dSYM at path 
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gmgvycoixcnkriauasdffkzvdg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app.dSYM
Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file. 
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. 
This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase
is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it.

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

What is wrong..? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you also check that `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` is set to `dwarf-with-dsym` for all configurations ?

Comment: @Alladinian Yes it is for both release and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. When moving framework to different folder I forgot to change run script from:

```
./Fabric.framework/run ...
```

to:

```
./Frameworks/Fabric.framework/run ...
```

Everything is working now.